# my code throwing this error message "Ambiguity between MainWindow.deviceIp and MainWindow.deviceIp"

Tags: c#

I'm creating a desktop payment form where you are able to connect a credit card machine via USB and IP, I created a radioButton to be able to switch from IP to USB, so if the device is set to USB the Ip fields should be invisible and the vise versa, however, when I'm trying to add a conditional for this to work, it's giving me the above error message for "_deviceIp"and "_ipPort"
"Ambiguity between MainWindow.deviceIp and MainWindow.deviceIp"

```
using PaymentEngine.xTransaction;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace cktest2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private TextBox _deviceIp;
        private TextBox _ipPort;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _deviceIp = this.FindName("deviceIp") as TextBox;
            _ipPort = this.FindName("ipPort") as TextBox;
        }

        
        void BasicParameters(PaymentEngine.xTransaction.Request cardknoxRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                cardknoxRequest.xKey = ApiKey.Text;
                cardknoxRequest.xVersion = "5.0.0";
                cardknoxRequest.xSoftwareName = "testing";
                cardknoxRequest.xSoftwareVersion = "2.0";
                cardknoxRequest.xCommand = command.Text;


            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }

        void DeviceParameters(PaymentEngine.xTransaction.Request cardknoxRequest)
        {

        }

        private void submitbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PaymentEngine.xTransaction.Request cardknoxRequest = new PaymentEngine.xTransaction.Request();
            string selectedCommand = command.Text;
            try
            {
                cardknoxRequest.EnableDeviceInsertSwipeTap = true;
                cardknoxRequest.Device_Set(deviceName.Text, devicePort.Text, "115200", "N", "8");
                cardknoxRequest.Device_Set(deviceName.Text, _deviceIp.Text, _ipPort.Text);

               

                if (deviceIpRadioButton.IsChecked == false)
                {
                    _deviceIp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    _ipPort.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else
                {
                    _deviceIp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    _ipPort.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }



            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }

            if (selectedCommand == "cc:sale")
            {

                BasicParameters(cardknoxRequest);

                cardknoxRequest.xAmount = 1;
                cardknoxRequest.xAllowDuplicate = true;

                PaymentEngine.xTransaction.Response cardknoxResponse = cardknoxRequest.ProcessOutOfScope();
                HandleResponse(cardknoxResponse);
            }
            else if (selectedCommand == "cc:void" || selectedCommand == "cc:refund")
            {
                BasicParameters(cardknoxRequest);

                string referenceNum = refNumber.Text;
                if (long.TryParse(referenceNum, out long longRef))
                {
                    cardknoxRequest.xRefNum = longRef;


                    PaymentEngine.xTransaction.Response cardknoxResponse = cardknoxRequest.Process();
                    HandleResponse(cardknoxResponse);
                } else
                {
                    response.Text = "Error: Ref number must be numeric";
                    response.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                    response.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }


                
            }
            else if (selectedCommand == "ebtfs:sale")
            {
                BasicParameters(cardknoxRequest);


                cardknoxRequest.xAmount = 1;
                PaymentEngine.xTransaction.Response cardknoxResponse = cardknoxRequest.ProcessOutOfScope();
                HandleResponse(cardknoxResponse);

            }
        }

        private void HandleResponse(Response cardknoxResponse)
        {
            response.Text = cardknoxResponse.FormattedResponse();
            response.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            if (cardknoxResponse.xResult == "A")
            {
                if (cardknoxResponse.xCommand == "cc:sale" || cardknoxResponse.xCommand == "cc:void" || cardknoxResponse.xCommand == "cc:refund" || cardknoxResponse.xCommand == "ebtfs:sale")
                {
                    response.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!(cardknoxResponse.xCommand == "cc:sale" || cardknoxResponse.xCommand == "cc:void" || cardknoxResponse.xCommand == "cc:refund" || cardknoxResponse.xCommand == "ebtfs:sale"))
                {
                    response.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                }
            }

            if (cardknoxResponse.xCommand == "cc:sale")
            {
                string refNum = cardknoxResponse.xRefNum;
                refNumber.Text = refNum;
            }
        }
```

XAML

````
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cktest2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="Beige">
        <Button x:Name="submitbtn" Content="Process" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,345,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Height="79" Click="submitbtn_Click" >
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#4CAF50"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#388E3C"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
            <Button.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFF"/>
            </Button.Foreground>
            <Button.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.7" ShadowDepth="3"/>
            </Button.Effect>
        </Button>
        <TextBox x:Name="ApiKey" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,28,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="cardktestaccoudev7973ce78b7584012a3ad439b1d65" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="267" Height="40" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.42,1.333"/>
        <Label Content="Key" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="86" FontSize="20" Foreground="#333333"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="command" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Padding="5">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="cc:sale"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="cc:void"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="cc:refund"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="ebtfs:sale"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="refNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,104,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="refnumber" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="30" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Padding="5" />
        <RadioButton x:Name="devicePortRadioButton" Content="Device Port" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="devicePortRadioButton_Checked" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.486,1.174"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="devicePort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="509,129,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="COM9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="40" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.076,0.549"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="deviceName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="635,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.486,1.84">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Verifone_P200.4"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Verifone_P400.4"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Verifone_MX915.4"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Pax_s300.3"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="response" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,159,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="60" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="_deviceIp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="635,180,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="192.168.1.2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="37" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.076,0.549" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="_ipPort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="521,180,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" RenderTransformOrigin="0.463,1.595" Height="37" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="deviceIpRadioButton"  Content="Device IP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,191,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,2.308" Checked="deviceIpRadioButton_Unchecked" Unchecked="DeviceIpRadioButton_Unchecked"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>```
````

Comment: I concur. There seems to be ambiguity for `_devicIP` and `_ipPort`. You've declared the same variables in both the XAML and in the code behind.